# custom roms - format data before or after flash?

Tags: rom-flashing, recovery-mode, twrp, formatting

Reading the XDA forums I've noticed some posts around custom ROM flashing instruct users to perform data format in a recovery (such as TWRP) at different times. My question is - should data format be performed prior to flashing the ROM image, or right after it? Does it even matter?

Comment: Follow the ROM developer installation instructions //Usually, you need to clear data *before* //Yes, it does matter because you get a clean installation

Comment: @beeshyams nah I meant does it matter whether it's flashed before or after - clearly it has to be at _some_ point.

Comment: [LineageOS recommends before flashing](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/sailfish/install/): "*This will remove encryption and delete all files stored in the internal storage, as well as format your cache partition (if you have one).*"

Comment: @AndrewT. exactly. Yet some others, e.g. EvolutionX, recommends doing it after ROM flash.